# Convert Object to Array using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How I convert this object to array using Laravel OR Help me to save this into database when object is dynamic

```
{
    "name":"nabnit jha",
    "email":"028nabnit@gmail.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "c_password":"123456",
    "imgUrl":"sonujha.jpg"
}
```

Simply I will do this if object property is not dynamic

```
public function insert($data, $modelName)
    {
        $modelName->name = $data->name;
        $modelName->email = $data->email;
        $modelName->password = $data->password;
        $modelName->img_url = $data->imgUrl;
        $modelName->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

I want to save this object to database in dynamic object case, for this I use foreach loop but not work.

```
 public function insert($data, $modelName)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $modelName->$key = $value;
        }

        $modelName->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Record Inserted Successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: How does this data get into the `insert()` method?  Do you `json_decode()` the data?  Does it show any errors?

Comment: You can use `$modelName->save($data)` as a shortcut but you need to ensure you have a `$fillable` or `$guarded` property on your model to determine what can be auto-filled

Answer (score 1):

To convert a PHP object to an array you can simply cast it as an array:

```php
$modelAsArray = (array) $modelName;
```

You could then create a model from this array like so:

```php
MyModel::create($modelAsArray);
```